# Hide Main Activity while using fragment

Tags: android-fragments

It has been awhile so I am struggling with fragments a bit. I am working on demos right now to get familiar again. What I am doing is in the main activity, I have a button to click which opens a fragment to enter information like name, address, etc. For some reason, the main activity doesn't go away and shows over the fragment. What am I doing wrong???

Note: I have not wired the cancel button yet to go back to Main Activity without doing anything.

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static User mUser = new User();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    Button requestServiceButton = findViewById(R.id.servicesButton);
    requestServiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
            NewUser fragment = new NewUser();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }

    });
```

**NewUser Class:**

```
public class NewUser extends Fragment {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_user, container, false);

    final EditText fName = v.findViewById(R.id.firstNameEditText);
    final EditText lName = v.findViewById(R.id.lastNameEditText);
    final EditText address = v.findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
    final EditText city = v.findViewById(R.id.cityEditText);
    final EditText email = v.findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailAddress);
    final EditText password = v.findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    final EditText phoneNumber = v.findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
    final EditText username = v.findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
    final EditText zipCode = v.findViewById(R.id.zipEditText);

    Button okButton = v.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MainActivity.mUser.setFirstName(fName.getText().toString());
            MainActivity.mUser.setLastName(lName.getText().toString());
            MainActivity.mUser.setAddress(address.getText().toString());
            MainActivity.mUser.setCity(city.getText().toString());
            MainActivity.mUser.setEmailAddress(email.getText().toString());
            MainActivity.mUser.setPassword(password.getText().toString());
            MainActivity.mUser.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber.getText().toString());
            MainActivity.mUser.setUsername(username.getText().toString());
            MainActivity.mUser.setZipCode(zipCode.getText().toString());

        }
    });

    Button cancelButton = v.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the xml layout which has the "R.id.fragmentHolder" id. What you mean by hide activity is a bit unclear. When you call "replace" with a fragment is that it will replace any existing fragment in that "R.id.fragmentHolder" container or if nothing is already there it will just add it. Hence fragemnts are only supposed to be held inside an activity not replace activities

Comment: My apologies. Basically I have my main screen and when a button is clicked, I want to go to another screen where information is entered, then you click "Submit" and stores everything and returns to main screen. I am only trying to show a fragment without having "R.layout.activity_main" being visible. I know this is a beginner question, it has just been years since I have done it and am having a brainfart for some reason.

Comment: I think what you probably want to do is to set the width and height "R.id.fragmentHolder" to match_parent so that the fragment UI will essentially take up the whole screen.If that doesn't work, then kindly share your "R.layout.activity_main" in the question. It would help in understanding the issue better

Comment: Thank you for the help. Once i reread what you sent, I realized that I need an empty activity to hold the fragments. I had the button in main activity then put a fragment over it. I simply moved everything from main activity into a "home_fragment" and switch from there. I greatly appreciate your help!!!! Thank you!